# Why does "android create project", give a main.xml with fill_parent, not match_parent, if fill_parent is out of date?

Tags: android, android-layout, sdk

Why does android create project, give a main.xml with fill_parent, not match_parent, if  fill_parent is out of date?

I've read many times that match_parent is what you're meant to use, not fill_parent.

Yet I see that when doing the `android create project` command

```
c:\androidsdktools\sdk\platform-tools>android create project --activity acto --p
ackage a.b.c --target "android-20" --path c:\bleeeeh
```

Looking at the main.xml that it generates

I see fill_parent used, rather than match_parent.

But this is the latest android sdk that I have downloaded.

```
c:\bleeeeh\res\layout>type main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout ..........
..........
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
........
</LinearLayout>

c:\bleeeeh\res\layout>
```

Just to show this is the latest android sdk as of writing..
downloaded in July 2014. Android-20

```
c:\androidsdktools\sdk\platforms>dir /ad
....
25/07/2014  09:56 AM    <DIR>          android-20
31/07/2014  10:32 PM    <DIR>          android-L
....
c:\androidsdktools\sdk\platforms>
```

Though I see posts even from 2012 saying fill_parent shouldn't be used, match_parent should be used.

So, why is android create project using fill_parent in main.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, why is android create project using fill_parent in main.xml?

First, `fill_parent` works just fine. While `match_parent` is the officially-preferred value, it maps to the same behavior as `fill_parent`.

Second, the project template used by **`android create project`** is not a particularly high priority for the Android tools team, in large part because **`android create project`** tool itself is not a particularly high priority for the Android tools team, when compared to Android Studio and Eclipse. I expect that either **`android create project`** will be discontinued entirely or replaced by something else in the fullness of time.

You are welcome to modify the layout files to use `match_parent` if you wish.

Bear in mind that **`android create project`** is designed to create projects that are built using the Ant build tool, and support for Ant is fading fast. You do not have to use an IDE if you do not want to, but you should consider migrating to Gradle for Android before too long.